# Where is the plain chain spec for kusama that i can use with a kusama runtime locally?

Tags: polkadot, runtime, kusama, chainspec

How to run polakdot/kusama runtime + node with a full functionality locally? what chain spec can I use? where the plan chain spec are located for just a ready to start for local env with 2 nodes?

Where i can find kusama/polakdot production plain chain spec to use with a real polkadot/runtime to test functionality locally?

Answer (score 1):

You can go to: https://github.com/polkadot-fellows/runtimes and build the repo.

And then:

```
./target/release/chain-spec-generator kusama-local
```