Where are the source code for polkadot runtime and the system parachains located?
Most of polkadot source code(substrate) is located in the polkadot-sdk repo, I think initially in the history of the monorepo the runtime sources for polkadot chains were also located there but quickly removed a the release cycles for polkadot and polkadot-sdk never could be aligned.
Where are the source code for polkadot and system parachains located?

https://substrate.stackexchange.com/questions/11047/where-is-the-plain-chain-spec-for-kusama-that-i-can-use-with-a-kusama-runtime-lo/11056#11056

@AurevoirXavier Thanks, the answer is a clear duplicate but the questions were different enough for me not to find it.

The source code for polkadot and system parachains can be found here
https://github.com/polkadot-fellows/runtimes

Found the link while the question was still being drafted
